# $m$ men and $n$ women in a roundtable

Tags: combinatorics

The question has been discussed before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135451/in-how-many-ways-m-men-and-n-women-can-sit-around-a-round-table-such-that-n).

The answer one of the respondents has given is $(m-1)! \cdot n! \cdot C(m,n)$.

I found the question solved in [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441930531).

Where the author has given the answer as (for no $2$ men sitting together):

$$m! \cdot n! \cdot [C(n-1,m-1) + C(n,m)]$$

I could follow his argument but could not understand why he didn't use $(n-1)!$ instead of $n!$ since we have circular permutations.

Here is the soln in the book.
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx4Iw.png)

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. Will do

Comment: @sidharth, Can you please upload the solution from the book?

Comment: I have added the solution

Comment: My 2 cents... and I'd love for someone else to post a proper answer. I think your specific question is why is it $m!n!$ and not $(m-1)!(n-1)!$ Generally you want to use $(n-1)!$ for circles because you don't want to double count arrangements. But in the solution the dude changes this from a circular arrangement problem to a line arrangement problem by fixing on a specific chair $X$ and looking at the two cases where a man is in the first chair of the line or a girl is. It is now a line arrangement problem. The solution has two components, one is figuring out where guys and girls can sit.

Comment: Part 2 of comment... The second component of the solution is now that you know where guys and girls can sit (how many acceptable arrangements) you can then multiply it by $m!n!$ to see how many arrangements of specific people you can get. Then you multiply the two components to get the final solution. So think of $X$ as the start of a line arrangement. If a girl is in $X$ or the start of the line, then the final seat can be whatever guy or girl. If a guy is in $X$ the start of the line, then the last position must be a girl which is why you get (n-1,m-1) as you used a man in the first spot etc